# R-Integrate an "integrated" function

Tags: r, integrate

I am using *integrate* function (in R) to numerically compute integrals. I have an univariate function with one argument *f(x,a)* like this (just for example purpose):

```
test = function(x,a) 1/sqrt(2*pi)*exp(-(x-a)^2/2)
```

I want to define new univariate function, which is a function of *a* after integrate the above function:

```
testa = function(a) integrate(test,0,Inf,a=a)$value #this works
```

Now my question is that is it possible to use *integrate* function on function *testa* ? For example:

```
integrate(testa,0,1) # not working
```

I tried and it is not working (got error message `evaluation of function gave a result of wrong length`). I already know that one can apply multivariate integration procedure directly on *test* (for example use *adaptIntegrate* function from *cubature* package). But that is not my purpose!

So does anyone know how to apply successively *integrate* function like the example above? Or confirm that this is not permitted in R?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 3):

`integrate` needs a vectorized function. You can use `Vectorize`:

```
integrate(Vectorize(testa),0,1)
#0.6843731905 with absolute error < 0.00000000000022
```

Disclaimer: I haven't checked the result for correctness.

Comment: Waoh this works! and thanks for your rapid answer! By the way, could you please explain the mechanism behind `Vectorize(testa)`. I also tried, for instance, `testa = function(a) integrate(Vectorize(test,vectorize.args='x',0,Inf,a =a )$value
` but it is not working. Thanks

Comment: `test` is already vectorized in x. There is no need to use `Vectorize` there. `help("Vectorize")` explains how it works.